# Admin LTE icon not working offline?

Tags: css, error-handling, icons, adminlte

Since several days I've been working with Admin LTE (admin template) but I'm surprised that the icons not working offline. so , is there any way to run all icon okey with offline too. In the below the picture is shown how its come without internet connection. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lya3.jpg)
Please suggest me a way to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By deafult AdminLTE call gets font-awesome css and fonts files from cdn, so without internet connection it can't call the resources.

To solve the problem, you should download font-awesome css and fonts and update urls in the stylesheet to point to the correct files on your computer or server. This should be a solution.